# Asynchronous API call failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have two methods for making an API call. The first, cleverly named apiCall, works exactly as expected. I pass a string url, and object to post, the call is made, and I receive an HttpResponseMessage class object:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage apiCall(string url, object o)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, o).Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return response;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I also have a method intended to make an asynchronous call. It is, very originally, named asyncApiCall, and is constructed as so:

```
public void asyncApiCall(string url, object o)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, o);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, this is the same method, minus the code to actually return a response from the server. However, the server is not receiving any sort of message.

In summary: My synchronous calls are working, and my async calls are failing. I would imagine I'm doing something wrong, but all of the documentation I've been able to find implies the HttpClient's PostAsJsonAsync method is asynchronous by default. Logically, I would expect (and have seen many instances of people having) the opposite problem.

Comment: You need to add an `await` to your `client.PostAsJsonAsync()` call. As you have it, I would imagine the `HttpClient` is being disposed before your `PostAsJsonAsync()` finishes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This needs to be awaited:

```
await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, o);
```

Which means this needs to be `async`:

```
public async Task asyncApiCall(string url, object o)
{
    //...
}
```

Otherwise what's likely happening is that control is leaving the `using` block before the task actually executes, causing the task to fail.  (since `client` is disposed.)  And since the task is never awaited or examined, the failure isn't reported anywhere.

Comment: This was exactly what was happening. I expected it to be something silly I had forgotten, and it was.